# how many $5$ digit numbers can be made

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We need to find how many $5$ digit numbers can be made by using $3$ **a**'s and $2$ **b**'s.

Any help will be appreciated. I have tried but nothing is happening.

Comment: Have you tried... listing them all? Just write them down, one by one. There aren't that many, and if you find some systematic way of doing it, you can also be pretty certain you haven't missed any.

Comment: yeah . im getting 10digit .is it all ?

Comment: Yeah, that's all of them. Now, if you edit your answer to say "I know there are ten because I've listed them, but I was wondering whether there was any way to actually calculate it directly", it would be a much better question post, and it ought to attract answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by choosing which of the positions 1,2,3,4,5 will be occupied by a's (since this also determines where the b's will go). This can be done in $$\binom{5}{3}=\frac{5\cdot4\cdot3}{3!}=\frac{60}{3\cdot2\cdot1}=\frac{60}{6}=10$$
ways.

(Note that choosing the positions of the b's and then letting the a's occupy the remaining spaces will also give you the correct solution, since $\binom{5}{3}=\binom{5}{5-3}=\binom{5}{2}$ by symmetry.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an answer to your question that uses basic combinations knowledge then it goes like this.
 Since you have $5$ spots and $5$ five letters to fill those spots you get the number of permutations as $5\times4\times3\times2\times1$ = $120$. Now, however, you will notice that there are $3$ $a's$ so that means that a lot of your arrangements will be repeated. As in you will get $aaabb$ and $aaabb$ as $2$ different permutations because in permutations order matters. 
 So to solve this you say that you can arrange $3$ $a's$ in $3!$ ways and $2$ $b's$ in $2!$ ways. The reason for this is that when you list out, so let's say that the three $a$'s are $a_1, a_2, a_3$ and the $b$'s are $b_1, b_2$. Now when you list out you will have six cases where the $3$ $a$'s are together but their order is different. 
That is $a_1a_2a_3b_1b_2$, $a_1a_3a_2b_1b_2$, $a_2a_1a_3b_1b_2$, $a_2a_3a_1b_1b_2$, $a_3a_2a_1b_1b_2$, $a_3a_1a_2b_1b_2$ which is six cases that are essentially the same number! So now you can see that $b$ will have $2$ such cases thus resulting in our next step.

Now divide $120$ by $3!\times2!$ and you get $\frac{120}{3\times2\times2}$ = 10. Which is what you did by listing. But when it comes to huge numbers you won't be able to list so you should try using this concept.